# Should I avoid using the word 「来日」 when referring to myself?

Tags: word-choice

I heard from my Japanese friends that I should avoid using the word 「来日」 when I'm outside of Japan.

Is it true, and, if it is, has this something to do with the kanji 「来」?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is true. 「来」 means *to come*.
If you are outside of Japan, you can use 「[訪日]{ほうにち}」 instead.
「訪」 means *to visit*.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the question :D OP probably knows the things I cover in my answer

Comment: There are regional differences though. For example on Kyushu it's very common to refer to yourself as "coming" somewhere instead of "going". (this is not standard Japanese though)

Answer (score 0):

The word 「来日{らいにち}」 means visiting Japan. The kanji 「日」 in that word is an abbreviation of 「日本{にほん}」 (Japan). The kanji 「来」 can be used to express coming somewhere, but I don't think there is a generally understood abbreviation method for every country.

One way to express arriving in a country:

> [country]に到着{とうちゃく}する (ni tōchaku suru)